# Which function do we use to show the isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

The automorphism group of the group $G$, $\text{Aut}(G)$, is the group of isomorphisms from $G$ to $G$.

It is the set of functions $\phi$ that send the generators of $G$ to the generators of $G$, right?

I want to show that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_6)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Since the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are $1$ and $5$, $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_6)$ is the set of functions that send $1$ to $1$ or to $5$ and $5$ to $1$ or $5$, or not?

Such a function is the identity function and the function $x\mapsto 5x$, right?

Which function do we use to show the isomorphism?

Comment: In your second line: it in fact is the set of bijective homomorphisms, not only functions from $\;G\;$ to itself.

Comment: Which other functions besides from $G$ ? @Joanpemo

Comment: All the permutations on $\;G\;$ as a set, @Mary Star. Most of these ones aren't automorphisms (group theory), just bijections (set theory).

Comment: Ah ok... I am a little confused how to find a function to show the isomorphism... Could you give me a hint? @Joanpemo

Comment: You don't need to explicitly define such a fuction. You have already answered the question. Remember that the group of automorphisms is by no means finite.  They can be classes of mappings.

Comment: @PhillipHamilton How is the group of automorphisms not finite in this case?

Comment: Excuse me *is by no means a finite set of functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're in the right track: any homomorphism from any group $\;G\;$ towards any group is completely determined by its action on some generating set of $\;G\;$. If we talk of automorphisms then generators are mapped to generators

In our case, $\;G:=\Bbb Z_6\;$ is a cyclic group of order 6, and thus an automorphism is completely determined by its action on a generator of $\;G\;$.

Since there are two elements of order six here, namely $\;1,5\pmod 6\;$ , every automorphism must map any of them into itself or the other one, and thus clearly Aut$\,(G)\cong\Bbb Z_2\;$

Comment: So every automorphism group of a group that has $2$ generators is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ because each generator is either mapped to itself or to the other elemens, as it happens in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes...but some care is due here. When you say "a group that has two generators" one can understand a group that NEEDS two elements to be generated. That is not our case here. What we have here is that $\;G\;$ , being cyclic, can be generated by one single element, and there are two possible candidates in this case to be that single element generating the group. For example $\;S_3\;$ is a group that needs at least two elements to be generated by them.

Comment: Ah ok... I see... Is this justification enough or do we have to proof the isomorphism by defining a function and showing that it is an homomorphism and a bijection?

Comment: We have that the possible generators of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ are $1,5$. The automorphisms map one generator to one of the others. So, the automorphisms are the following functions: $$f_1(x)=x, f_2(x)=5x$$ Could we show that the two groups are isomorphic to each other by defining the function $$h:\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_6)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \text{ with } \\ f_1\mapsto 0\pmod 2 \\ f_2\mapsto 1\pmod 2$$ and show that it is bijective and an homomorphism?

Comment: I think you meant $\;\Bbb Z_6\;$ above, and yes: your $\;h\;$ works fine, in my opinion.

Comment: Is this $h$ bijective because for each element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $x$, there is an element of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_6)$ that is mapped to one $x$?

Comment: As for the homomorphism: 

$$(f_1\circ f_1)(x)=f_1(f_1(x))=f_1(x)=x$$ 
So we have $h(f_1\circ f_1)=h(f_1)=0\pmod 2=0\pmod 2+0\pmod 2=h(f_1)+h(f_1)$ 

$$(f_1 \circ f_2)(x)=f_1(f_2(x))=f_1(5x)=5x=f_2$$ 
So we have $h(f_1\circ f_2)=h(f_2)=1\pmod 2=0\pmod 2+1\pmod 2=h(f_1)+h(f_2)$ 

$$(f_2\circ f_1)(x)=f_2(f_1(x))=f_2(x)$$ 
So we have $h(f_2\circ f_2)=h(f_2)=1\pmod 2=1\pmod 2+0\pmod 2=h(f_2)+h(f_1)$ 
 
$$(f_2\circ f_2)(x)=f_2(f_2 (x))=f_2(5x)=5(5x)\equiv-(-x)=x$$ 
So we have $h(f_2\circ f_2)=h(f_1)=0\pmod 2=1\pmod 2+1\pmod 2=h(f_2)+h(f_2)$  
$$$$ 
So it is an homomorphism.

Comment: Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Looks fine though a little messy. Hard to follow, but the basis seems to be sound.

Comment: How could we improve it? Is the justification why $h$ is bijective correct?

Comment: @MaryStar At the point of the question, one usually already knows that the set of automorphisms of a group, under composition, is a group. Indicating that any autom. is completely determined by the way it sends generators to generators is already enough to deduce that in this case the autom. group is of order two, and since there's only one single group of order two up to isomorphism that's enough! No need to actually write all what you wrote.